# How can I test if 2 datetimes represent the same clock time (ignoring the date) in R?

Tags: r, datetime, time

In R, I have 2 POSIXct (i.e. date+time) vectors, and I would like to test if they represent the same clock time, regardless of date. For example:

```
library(lubridate)
# 1:12:57 PM in NYC
dttm1 <- ymd_hms("1993-10-15 13:12:57", tz = "America/New_York")
# Also 1:12:57 PM in NYC, on a different day
dttm2 <- ymd_hms("2007-2-27 17:12:57", tz = "UTC")
# 1:12:57 PM, but not in NYC
dttm3 <- ymd_hms("2007-2-27 13:12:57", tz = "UTC")
# Not 1:12:57 PM in any time zone
dttm4 <- ymd_hms("1963-1-15 01:12:57", tz = "UTC")
```

Is there a function that will tell me which of these datetimes represent the same clock time? Such a function should return TRUE for `dttm1` and `dttm2` and FALSE for any other pair of the above dates. Ideally this function would be vectorized to work element-wise on vectors of datetimes. If such a function only works for datetimes in the same time zone or requires specifying a time zone in which the comparison should be performed, that would be fine. (For bonus points, a 2nd function that returns TRUE for only `dttm1` and `dttm3` would be nice as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I must be reinventing the wheel here, but you could do:

```r
utc_time <- function(x, convert = TRUE) {
 if (convert) x <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
 substr(x, 12, 19)
}
```

So that by default, you get the UTC-converted time as a string

```
utc_time(dttm1)
#> [1] "17:12:57"

utc_time(dttm2)
#> [1] "17:12:57"

utc_time(dttm1) == utc_time(dttm2)
#> [1] TRUE

utc_time(dttm3)
#> [1] "13:12:57"

utc_time(dttm3) == utc_time(dttm1)
#> [1] FALSE
```

But if you want the option to *not* convert date times, then specify `convert = FALSE`:

```
utc_time(dttm1, convert = FALSE) == utc_time(dttm3, convert = FALSE)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do:

```
mytime <- function(x)  as.numeric(x) %% 86400

mytime(dttm1) == mytime(c(dttm2,dttm3, dttm4))

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I don't want the function to return TRUE for `dttm1` and `dttm3`. (I asked in parentheses for a *separate* function to do this.)